# Installed Miktex but unable to run from command prompt

Tags: pdftex, miktex, pandoc

[image]I have installed Miktex and Texworks in Windows 10. How to invoke latex from the command prompt? I want to use Pandocs to convert files into pdf (it uses latex). For example: I want to run this command in cmd: pandoc -f html -t pdf http://najeebkhan.github.io/blog/VecCal.html -s -o try.pdf

In the attached image (see the last line): It can be seen that I have added the miktex to the path variable.

I have reinstalled miktex. On running tex -v . I get this message in the tex.log file: "FATAL tex - The command line options could not be processed." But I am able to compile file with GUI of texstudio. Following is complete content of log file:
2017-04-30 12:59:33,648+0200 INFO  tex - starting with command line: tex -v
2017-04-30 12:59:33,653+0200 INFO  tex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - The command line options could not be processed.
2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - Info: optionError="unknown option"
2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\webapp.cpp
2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - Line: 339

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does `tex -v` output a TeX version number?

Comment: Are you able  to create a LaTeX hello word document and compile that? Or does the terminal give back: Command pdflatex not found?

Comment: @TeXnician On typing: tex -v
Output: 'tex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Miktex is installed: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64

Comment: @Johannes_B 'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Miktex is installed: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64

Comment: That means you didn't install MikTeX, the instalation did not fully succeed, or the PATH varible wasn't set properly and your OS can't find the executable.

Comment: Yeah, that's logically. Your path is not in the global PATH. Please add it to that (there are tons of tutorials how to do that). Then restart the cmd.

Comment: @TeXnician Before asking this question I had searched in internet and I had allready added miktex to the path. In the attached image: It can be seen that I have added the miktex to the path variable.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall (best for all users)?

Comment: @Johannes_B Before asking this question I had searched in internet and I had already added miktex to the path. In the attached image: It can be seen that I have added the miktex to the path variable. Miktex is working via GUI. I am able to create latex document through Texworks invoked in windows desktop. DO you still think that the installation is not proper?

Comment: You could have added that you can create document using texworks as GUI. That would have made all the comments we had been given pointless. Please add the information to the question.

Comment: @TeXnician I have reinstalled miktex for all users. On running tex -v . I get this message in the tex.log file: "FATAL tex - The command line options could not be processed." But I am able to compile file with GUI of texstudio.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have reinstalled miktex for all users. On running tex -v . I get this message in the tex.log file: "FATAL tex - The command line options could not be processed." But I am able to compile file with GUI of texstudio. Added in the question also.

Comment: Open the log file of such a GUI created document and look at path the stuff is taken from. I bet it is taken from `C:\something` rather than appdata.

Comment: @Johannes_B Following is complete contents of the log file:  
2017-04-30 12:59:33,648+0200 INFO  tex - starting with command line: tex -v  
2017-04-30 12:59:33,653+0200 INFO  tex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
<br/>2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - The command line options could not be processed.
<br/>2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - Info: optionError="unknown option"
<br/>2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\webapp.cpp
<br/>2017-04-30 12:59:45,185+0200 FATAL tex - Line: 339

Comment: @Nikhil You can edit that to the question. It will get pushed back on top of the main page with evey edit, so more users see that there are news to the question. Including me. No need to ping me personally for every little detail.

Comment: `tex -v` doesn't work in miktex. The correct command line call is e.g. `tex --version`.

Comment: Beside this: stop to change your system. It is impossible to help someone who got in installation frenzy - it is then quite unclear which information is still current and which is outdated. Edit your question so that it reflect the current state and shows the first problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as [Nikhil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/123977/nikhil), saw that the answer was given in the comment from [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367452/installed-miktex-but-unable-to-run-from-command-prompt#comment906306_367452) buried near the bottom, and thought I would put it together here with necessary modifications:

1. Installed Pandoc and Miktex
2. Verify Pandoc with `pandoc -v` in CMD
3. Verify Miktex with `tex --version`, **not** `tex -v` in CMD.
4. Test OP's conversion code with slight modifications: `pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars -t latex  http://najeebk.com/blog/VecCal.html -s --mathjax -o try3.pdf`
5. PDF was generated with proper math formatting thanks to `html+tex_math_dollars` extension, also had to switch `-t pdf` to `-t latex` per Pandoc documentation.